# Invalid redeclaraciton of property for protocol when base class has optional property of same name

Tags: swift, properties, swift-protocols

I have a protocol that has a property `name: String`. I have a base class that has a property of `name: String?`. When I try to adopt the protocol, I keep getting invalid redeclaration error. How do I redeclare a property of the same name but optional?

[image]

```
protocol Targetable {
    var id: String { get }
    var name: String { get }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have several properties with the same name, but different types, so you cannot achieve what you are trying to achieve. Even if you changed the type of `name` of a completely unrelated type (let's say `Int`), you'd get the same error, this has nothing to do with one of the two declarations being `Optional`.